# Rails - How to retrieve audio from cloudinary to heroku using rails

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, cloudinary

Im creating a post model with Audio inside.

Im deploy my app into heroku, and store all files to cloudinary.

And audio successfully sent to the cloud and Audio can be play on localhost

But the problem is

> I cant retrieve the audio on my rails app(on heroku).
>
> This just looks like a blank play button with no audio

I have tried these codes :

```
<%= cl_video_tag @post.audio.url, controls: true, style: "width: 100%;" %>
```

and

```
<%= cloudinary_url @post.audio.url, :resource_type=>"video  %>
```

and

```
<audio controls="true" src="<%= cloudinary_url @post.audio.url, :resource_type=>"video" %>" style="width: 100%"></audio>
```

Thanks you for your help..

This is my post model

```
has_attached_file :audio, :storage => :cloudinary,
:cloudinary_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/cloudinary.yml"),
:path => ':id/:style/:filename',
:cloudinary_resource_type => :video, :processors => [:transcoder]
```

And in my post form

```
<%= f.file_field :audio %>
```

Comment: I assume you also have a form for submitting the audio file to Cloudinary? I would check two things: 1) `heroku logs --tail` to tail your logs and see what happens when you submit the form to create `@post.audio`. 2) Assuming that all looks good, `heroku run rails c` to get a Rails console on Heroku and verify your `post.audio.url`.

Comment: i just added my post model and my post form.. Take a look sir. Thank u

Comment: My guess is a credentials issue in your production environment. See my comment above about `heroku logs --tail`. See what happens when you submit your form on Heroku.